# google storage: gsutil unable to upload large files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

when trying too upload large files (> +- 150 MB) I often see

```
/usr/local/bin/gsutil/gsutil -m rsync /home/danny/data/video/2007/20070428/gpg gs://[my-bucket]/2007/20070428/

Copying file:///home/danny/data/video/2007/20070428/gpg/MVI_0747.AVI.gpg [Content-Type=application/pgp-encrypted]...
'RsyncCommand' object has no attribute 'copy_failure_count'
```

these files don't show up in the bucket, and are selected for resend every time I rerun rsync

this happens with a normal bucket, as well as a DRA bucket. both in the EU location.

any idea what I might be doing wrong?

regards, Danny.

Comment: This is [issue #205](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/205)

Comment: ok, upgraded to pre-release version of gsutil, seems to work... thanks!

Comment: Great, posted as an answer below for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem reported in [issue #205](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/205) on GitHub. It will be fixed in an upcoming release due out shortly, but there is a workaround and a pre-release available in the issue thread.